# Outside link for Add to Cart

Tags: magento, acrobat

We want to get an outside link for a Magento-store page, that would add to cart an item that's linked from a PDF link (it's a technical drawing with some parts that can be ordered separately)
I see that Magento uses JavaScript onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)", but it can not be triggered to the specific item like this. 
Is there any way this can be solved?

BR-:g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the basic url to call:

```
www.example.com/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]
```

If you want more details on how to do it with options etc. take a look here:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring

Comment: thank you! it works great. Just one more question: how can I return to Acrobat from the clicked link? It would be the best if it appears for a moment that it was inserted in the Cart, and then it gets back to the pdf from where it was triggered.

Comment: @Gershon  This my simple cms page, add to cart not working could you pls help me solve this issue -> code https://justpaste.it/40ryd

Answer (score 4):

You can give add to cart url like:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always loop over your product collection and ask the checkout/cart helper for the url:

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
/* @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection */
//... add filters to collection as appropriate

$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
/* @var $cartHelper Mage_Checkout_Helper_Cart */

foreach( $collection as $product ){
    /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
    $atcUrl = $carthelper->getAddUrl($product);
    //... do what you need to with the above value (echo, fwrite, etc);
}
```

Note that you can also pass in product-type-specific options as a second param.

Comment: Are you aware of how to pass simple product custom options through using the second paramenter of getAddUrl()?